# Multiple elements with the same ref, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem. It is:

```
let list = storage.map((element, index, array) => {
  return (
    <li key={index} className="list-element">
      <div className="title-wrapper" onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}>
        <p className="title">{array[index]['title']}</p>
        <p className="title title-full" ref={node => this.title = node}>Text</p>
      </div>
    </li>
      );
}); 
handleMouseEnter() {
    this.title.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

So, when mouse enters .title-wrapper I want to set opacity to 1 on .title-full. But no matter on which .title-wrapper mouse enters, always opacity will be set to the last .title-full.
The problem is easy to solve with querySelector but I read that using it is bad thing in React, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `this.title` is always set to the last element is because you are setting each element in the loop to `this.title`, so the last one overwrites the one before it, and so on.

What about just using CSS directly, instead of handling it in React at all?
Example:

```
.title-wrapper:hover .title-full {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I assumed incorrectly that when .title-full gets opacity 1 then hover stops working on .title-wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Just a general comment that refs aren't usually preferred in React (maybe for forms or modals sometimes). What you're emulating is a jQuery-like DOM manipulation approach, which can certainly work but is sidestepping the power of React being state-based, obvious, and easy to follow.

I would typically

```
this.setState({
   hovered: true
})
```

in your `handleMouseEnter` method (and unset it in your mouseOut). Then choose your className based on `this.state.hovered`

Comment: But what if I have lots of .title-full elements? How how can I get to know on which concrete element should I set that state.

Answer (score 1):

I think going with CSS is definitely the best approach.

Just for anyone running into this issue of multiple refs in another context, you could solve the issue by storing the refs in an array

```
let list = storage.map((element, index, array) => {
  return (
    <li key={index} className="list-element">
      <div className="title-wrapper" onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseEnter(index)}>
        <p className="title">{array[index]['title']}</p>
        <p className="title title-full" ref={node => this.titles[index] = node}>Text</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}); 

handleMouseEnter(index) {
  this.titles[index].style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Again, you don't need to do this for your use case, just thought it might be helpful for others :D